# Validating id with Guardian 1 and Phoenix 1.3

Tags: elixir, jwt, phoenix-framework, guardian

I use Guardian 1 and Phoenix 1.3. And I'm trying to make an API that uses JWT. I now have authentication working for routes. For example, you cannot access `get api/users/` without having a valid token in the header.

I have a pipeline that looks like:

```
defmodule PhxAuthApi.Auth.AuthPipeline do

  use Guardian.Plug.Pipeline, otp_app: :phx_auth_api,
    module: PhxAuthApi.Auth.Guardian,
    error_handler: PhxAuthApi.Auth.AuthErrorHandler

  plug Guardian.Plug.VerifyHeader, claims: %{"typ" => "access"}, realm: :none
  plug Guardian.Plug.EnsureAuthenticated
  plug Guardian.Plug.LoadResource, ensure: true

end
```

What I want to achieve is that a user calling `put api/users/1` only can access that route if the user has the corresponding `:id` in the token resource. 
I know I can get the resource by calling

```
resource = Guardian.Plug.current_resource(conn)
```

But how would I go about doing this? making another pipeline?

How would that look, I couldn't find any documentation on achieving this?

I'm am fairly new to Elixir and Phoenix and this is my first project that I intend to ship.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to create another [`Plug`](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/readme.html) that is to be included in the same pipeline after `Guardian.Plug.LoadResource`.

At this point the resource is already loaded and what you need is to implement `call` callback to deny an access unless the user has the corresponding `:id` in their token resource.

Comment: Could you please add an example of how to achieve this?

Comment: The documentation page for `Plug` I linked contains [an example](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/readme.html#the-plug-conn): just `send_resp(conn, 403, "Access Denied")` from `Plug.call/2` if the condition was not met.